# How to fix problem with tracking total time elapsed using end time - start time?

Tags: python, debugging, time

Currently I am trying to use `Pymem` to track the amount of time an app is opened. 
I've tried implementing it using the technique of;

```
endTime - startTime
```

using `time.time()` but I'm not sure why it doesn't return the correct value.

I checked the logic behind my code, and which parts of the code runs throughout the many loops. I used `"count"` to make sure the code ends so that I could read the output values, but when I counted times such as 6 seconds, the program returned a very small decimal in the thousandths place.

Here is the code:

```
from pymem import Pymem
import pymem
import time

# Must install pymem (pip install pymem)

timeElasped = 0
startTime = 0
endTime = 0
trackTime = False

count = 0                                               # Count is just to make sure code terminates to debug


while (True):
# LeagueClient.exe
    try:
        pm = Pymem('Notepad.exe')                       # Checks if LeagueClient.exe is running (Determines which process we are targeting)
        
        startTime = time.time()
        trackTime = True   
        print('League of Legends is running....')    

    except:                                             # If LeagueClient.exe is not running
        print ('League of Legends is not running....')
        endTime = time.time()
        
        if (trackTime == True):
            timeElasped = endTime - startTime

            
        trackTime = False
            
        print(timeElasped)
        count += 1
        
        if (count == 1000):
            exit()
```

Comment: Well, I think this code has other issues as well, but the very first time your exception is triggered (which will happen almost immediately after you set your last `startTime`), you then disable tracking of time (which will never be enabled again). Your code then presumable quickly fails 999 times more and exists, never having touched `timeElapsed` again. It's not clear what time span you are trying to measure. You are currently measuring time from when it last worked until it first failed, which is indeed very short.